# CRAN submission - R CMD Check warning - compilation flags used

Tags: r, r-package, cran

I am trying to submit my first package to `CRAN` and on my machine, I am getting the following warning on running `R CMD check` (via `RStudio`)

```
checking compilation flags used ... WARNING
Compilation used the following non-portable flag(s):
  ‘-Wno-unused-function’ ‘-Wno-unused-variable’
including flag(s) suppressing warnings
R CMD check results
0 errors | 1 warning  | 0 notes

R CMD check succeeded
```

I don't get this warning on building my package on `R` win-builder. I do get a `NOTE` from the win-builder service, but I think this is due to the fact that this is the first submission and there are spellings that `CRAN` does not recognize, i.e.,

```
* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE

New submission

Possibly mis-spelled words in DESCRIPTION:
  CVODE (8:167)
  CVODES (8:219)
  Livermore (8:108)
```

I am not so worried about the first submission and the mis-spelled words note as I can explain them in the comments (and in `cran-comments.md` file). But is there a way to remove the warnings I get on my system (`macOS`, `R = 3.5.0`). The package builds fine on `travis-ci` and `appveyor`.

Also, is the package ready for submission with the 1 warning, I know that Hadley's book mentions that we must try to remove ALL errors, warnings and notes before submission.

I just found out about `r-hub`, the package builds fine on it

```
Build ID:   sundialr_0.1.0.tar.gz-aa50507b5a2a8b57b091643fa3e7aae2
Platform:   Debian Linux, R-devel, GCC
Submitted:  3 minutes 36.3 seconds ago
Build time: 3 minutes 32.1 seconds
```

The package code can be found [here](https://github.com/sn248/sundialr)

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: You should use single quotes for non-English words or names of other packages and external software. Any maybe you could rephrase the second sentence a bit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update May 2019**: [Recent changes](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-package-devel/2019q2/003925.html) in the Debian packages have made these configuration changes unnecessary for the latest packages.

AFAIK these flags are used by Debian as default for every compilation. And R memorizes the flags that where used. You can adjust that in `~/.R/Makevars`, e.g.:

```
# Settings from /etc/R/Makeconf with "non-portable flag(s):"
# ‘-Wdate-time’ ‘-Werror=format-security’ ‘-Wformat’ replaced by -Wall -pedantic
# and without -fdebug-prefix-map=... 
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 $(LTO)
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 $(LTO)
CXX98FLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
CXX11FLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
CXX14FLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
```

Comment: Note: if you are not sure about the localization of the Makevars file, you can use: `usethis::edit_r_makevars()`