# I receive a fatal error with boost and Rcpp

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp, multiprecision, boost-multiprecision

As described in the post:

[Rcpp and boost: it should work but it does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52876341/rcpp-and-boost-it-should-work-but-it-does-not)

I am trying to use boost in Rcpp in Windows. The (simplified) file is:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::string qexp(double da = -1500.0, double db = -1501.0)
{
  mp::float128 a(da), b(db);
  mp::float128 res = mp::exp(a) / (mp::exp(a) + mp::exp(b));
  return res.convert_to<std::string>();
}
```

I had a compile problem. As @duckmayr suggested in that post, I tried with:

`Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS" = "-lquadmath")`

and then `Rcpp::sourceCpp('quadexp.cpp')`

In this way, the compilation runs without errors. But then, when I execute qexp(), I get a message in RStudio about "fatal error", and RStudio shuts down completely. Do you know what could be happening? I assume my problem is due to some kind of configuration I have, since @duckmayr could run the same code without problems. What parts of my configuration should look at, in order to avoid this nasty "fatal error"?

Comment: 1. His suggestion for `Sys.setenv()` was _for a different operating system_ on which I don't even need his suggestion.  2. Boost and RStudio have at times conflicted (mostly overthreading), I am not sure if that is the case here.  3.  The logical consequence of the previous point is to try the code in R _outside_ of RStudio.  4. As I said in response to your previous (identical?) question, "it just works for me" on Linux with standard CRAN packages.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment above:

```
edd@rob:~/git/so-r/52933795$ cat code.cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::string qexp(double da = -1500.0, double db = -1501.0) {
    mp::float128 a(da), b(db);
    mp::float128 res = mp::exp(a) / (mp::exp(a) + mp::exp(b));
    return res.convert_to<std::string>();
}


/*** R
qexp()
*/
edd@rob:~/git/so-r/52933795$ Rscript -e 'Rcpp::sourceCpp("code.cpp")'

R> qexp()
[1] "0.731058578630004879251159241821836351"
edd@rob:~/git/so-r/52933795$
```

*I.e.* using exactly your code (plus an added R invocation) it just works "as is".

Comment: OK, I have updated gcc to 8.1.0, and now RStudio does not crashes, and it gives the right output. Strange.

Comment: R (on Windows) does not use gcc 8.1.0.  Did you now switch platforms?  But I suspect that some compiler builds you are using do include , and some don't. I vaguely recall that it something new-ish, maybe g++ 4.* ?

Comment: I saw an answer in stackoverflow of this problem being solved by switching to gcc 6.1. I have googled, and I have found a way to install gcc 8.1 instead of the 4.something in Rtools. Now it works! (no other change).

Comment: @AnarcocapitalistaSocialdemocr Probably related: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/368/